# droid@screen runs into error ' Unsupported protocol: 2' when taking screenshot from Samsung TAB A 2108

Tags: android, adb, screenshot

On Ubuntu and Windows I get the same error. When I start droid@screen 1.2 (same with 1.1) and connect the device, droid@screen shows the device in the main screen and the device's window appears, but will stay empty/grey. The status info of the windows is 'OFFLINE'. The shell prints following output:

```
2019-08-19 18:05:23,169 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - parseArgs: []
2019-08-19 18:05:23,169 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - initProperties
2019-08-19 18:05:23,197 DEBUG Settings - --- Application Settings ---
2019-08-19 18:05:23,290 DEBUG Settings -   adbExecutable: /home/chris/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
2019-08-19 18:05:23,290 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - initCommands
2019-08-19 18:05:23,296 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - initGUI
2019-08-19 18:05:23,920 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - initAndroid
2019-08-19 18:05:23,980 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - run
2019-08-19 18:05:23,984 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - postStart
2019-08-19 18:05:24,228 INFO  AndroidDeviceManager - ADB changed
2019-08-19 18:05:24,229 INFO  AndroidDeviceManager - Connected to ADB via /127.0.0.1:5037
2019-08-19 18:05:24,260 INFO  AndroidDeviceManager - Device     connected: 52e7aa27
2019-08-19 18:05:24,262 DEBUG DroidAtScreenApplication - connected: dev=52e7aa27 (device)
2019-08-19 18:05:24,270 DEBUG DeviceFrame:52e7aa27 - DeviceFrame(device=52e7aa27 (device))
2019-08-19 18:05:24,361 DEBUG AndroidDeviceManager - Device changed: 52e7aa27, mask=CHANGE_BUILD_INFO 
06:05:24 E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2
06:05:25 E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2
....
```

Screen capture with Android Studio works fine! Android Version on the device is 9.